# Computing intersections between a large number of sets: doing it sequentially vs. sending everything to Intersection[...]

Tags: intersection

Say we want to compute the largest common subset among a very large number of sets $Q_i$.  One option would be to simply run the command:

```
Intersection[Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, Q7, ...];
```

However, this seems to choke for very large numbers of input sets ($10^4$ or so with on-order $10^2$ elements each).  Another option would be compute `Q12 = Intersection[Q1,Q2]`, then `Q123 = Intersection[Q12,Q3]`, then `Q1234 = Intersection[Q123,Q4]`, and so forth.

Are these two procedures equivalent?  Is there a better way?

Comment: They are not equivalent. I think nesting them is a bad idea, because the function `Intersection[]` do support multiple list. In general I always try to use those function that support exactly what I need them to and no more, because it seems to me quicker that way.

Comment: What you are asking for is `Fold[Intersection, First@#, Rest@#] &@list` but it is slower.

Comment: @Coolwater the final result *should* be equivalent though.

Comment: @Kuba Just to check, is the procedure you suggest the same as the one I'm talking about where the number of intersection operations required is exactly proportional to the length of the sets?

Comment: @CA30 Take a look at `Fold` in documentation. It does exactly n-1 intersections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Kuba notes using [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fold.html) is the most canonical way to implement your "sequential" algorithm in *Mathematica*.  Performance it best determined by simply [`Timing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Timing.html) your operation.

```
SeedRandom[1]
sets = RandomInteger[200, {10000, 1600}];

Intersection @@ sets // Timing
Fold[Intersection, #, {##2}] & @@ sets // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.983, {12, 90, 94, 101, 164}}
>
> {1.045, {12, 90, 94, 101, 164}}
> ```

(Timings performed in *Mathematica* 7 under Windows 7.)

So we see that the sequential method is if anything slightly slower than the direct application of [`Intersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Intersection.html).  I think it is probable that `Intersection` is already using this algorithm.

Regarding your second question:  ***Is there a better way?***  There can be, depending on your data.  In the example above there is a lot of duplication within each set, and eliminating this beforehand greatly speeds the operation of `Intersection`:

```
Intersection @@ (DeleteDuplicates /@ sets) // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.172, {12, 90, 94, 101, 164}}
> ```